# DataAdapter.Update() returns 1 without updating database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, dataadapter, sql-update

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I am unable to find the solution anywhere. It is most likely something obvious but I am now blinded by my own code.

I am trying to update my database with information from some text boxes. While debuging I am able to see that the DataTable row is being updated with the changes and dataadapter.update is returning 1. But when I check my database afterwords its has no changes. The strange part is that it works on my first update call, but not on the other.

I am closing the connections after use.

I have tried a few different ways to make this happen but no matter what I try I cant get this to work. I created it as equal as possible (as I'm new to this) to the one working, but still nothing. I tried creating my own updatecommand for the update as well.

This is my command:

```
    private SqlCeCommand createCharInstanceCommand()
    {
        SqlCeCommand updateCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
        updateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [CharacterClassInstance] SET " +
            "[CharID] = @p1, [ClassID] = @p2, [Lvl] = @p3, [SpellsKnown0] = @p4, [SpellsKnown1] = @p5, [SpellsKnown2] = @p6, " +
            "[SpellsKnown3] = @p7, [SpellsKnown4] = @p8, [SpellsKnown5] = @p9, [SpellsKnown6] = @p10, [SpellsKnown7] = @p11, " +
            "[SpellsKnown8] = @p12, [SpellsKnown9] = @p13, [SpellsPrDay0] = @p14, [SpellsPrDay1] = @p15, [SpellsPrDay2] = @p16, " +
            "[SpellsPrDay3] = @p17, [SpellsPrDay4] = @p18, [SpellsPrDay5] = @p19, [SpellsPrDay6] = @p20, [SpellsPrDay7] = @p21, " +
            "[SpellsPrDay8] = @p22, [SpellsPrDay9] = @p23, [SpellSaveDC0] = @p24, [SpellSaveDC1] = @p25, [SpellSaveDC2] = @p26, " +
            "[SpellSaveDC3] = @p27, [SpellSaveDC4] = @p28, [SpellSaveDC5] = @p29, [SpellSaveDC6] = @p30, [SpellSaveDC7] = @p31, " +
            "[SpellSaveDC8] = @p32, [SpellSaveDC9] = @p33, [BonusSpell1] = @p34, [BonusSpell2] = @p35, [BonusSpell3] = @p36, " +
            "[BonusSpell4] = @p37, [BonusSpell5] = @p38, [BonusSpell6] = @p39, [BonusSpell7] = @p40, [BonusSpell8] = @p41, [BonusSpell9] = @p42 " +
            "WHERE ([ClassInstanceID] = @p43)";

        for (int i = 1; i <=43;i++)
        {
            if (i == 43) updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p43", chosenClassInstance);
            else updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + i, dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1].ItemArray.GetValue(i).ToString());
        }
        return updateCommand;
    }
```

Here is the code that is supposed to update table (version nr 8 i think). I added rowmodified as one of my lasts attempts as it was not certain that the row registered as modified for some reason.

```
    private void updateClassInstance()
    {
        DataRow row = dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1];

        for (int i = 4; i <= 42; i++)
        {
            if (i <= 23) row[i] = Convert.ToInt32(spellInfoBoxes[i - 4].Text);
            if (i >= 34) row[i] = Convert.ToInt32(spellInfoBoxes[i - 14].Text);
        }
        try 
        { 
            dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1].AcceptChanges(); 
            dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1].SetModified(); 
        }
        catch { }

        int spellinfotest = this.classDataAdapter.Update(dClassInstance);
        this.classConnection.Close();
    }
```

The creation of the data adapter and command.

```
    private void fillSpellInfo()
    {
        classConnection = new SqlCeConnection(sConnectionString);

        string sqlClassInstance = "SELECT * " +
                                    "FROM CharacterClassInstance " +
                                    "WHERE (CharID = " + iCharacterID + 
                                    //") AND (ClassInstanceID = "+chosenClassInstance+
                                    ")";

        SqlCeCommand selectClassInstance = classConnection.CreateCommand();
        selectClassInstance.CommandText = sqlClassInstance;

        this.classConnection.Open();

        classDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(selectClassInstance);
        //SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(classDataAdapter);



        //classDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();


        dClassInstance = new DataTable();

        classDataAdapter.Fill(dClassInstance);

        classDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = createCharInstanceCommand();

        dClassInstance.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ClassInstanceID = " + chosenClassInstance;

        setSpellInfoValues();
        this.classConnection.Close();
    }
```

For some reason it works with the standard generated command on another data adapter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out why my code was not working. 
The problem is located in the building of the UpdateCommand, or rather the assigning of the parameters. In my limited knowledge I followed an example blindly and did not see the error until I wrote an update for another collection of fields by myself.

What happened was that the parameters got the old values because they got added when I build the DataAdapter and not after the updates were done. I suspect there are better ways of assigning the variables than addWithValue() but at least it works right now ;)
Live and learn someone said :)

To solve my problem I moved this code

```
classDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = createCharInstanceCommand();
```

into the part where I actually run the update:

```
        private void updateClassInstance()
    {
        DataRow row = dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1];

        for (int i = 4; i <= 42; i++)
        {
            if (i <= 23) row[i] = Convert.ToInt32(spellInfoBoxes[i - 4].Text);
            if (i >= 34) row[i] = Convert.ToInt32(spellInfoBoxes[i - 14].Text);
        }
        try
        {
            dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1].AcceptChanges();
            dClassInstance.Rows[chosenClassInstance - 1].SetModified();
        }
        catch { }

        classDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = createCharInstanceCommand();
        classDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = classConnection;

        int spellinfotest = this.classDataAdapter.Update(dClassInstance);
        this.classConnection.Close();
    }
```